# Angular - Creating Dropdowns and selecting the default value to be selected

Tags: angular, foreign-keys, dropdown

I am displaying a set of records (from a database) in a grid and a couple of the columns are foreign keys.

Example Record has Item , Quantity, Purchase Date. The Item in the record is an Item ID and is a foreign key.

I am getting the items from the Item Master (Id and Name) and creating dynamic dropdowns for the Item column. I am able to create the dropdowns as shown in the code segment below but they do not show the item based on the ID in the record. Not sure how do I do that.

```
     <select [(ngModel)]=item name='item' id="item">
          <option *ngFor="let itm of items" [value]=itm.Id>{{itm.name}}</option>
     </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it using following way

In HTML:

```html
<select [compareWith]="compareFn"  [(ngModel)]="item" name="item" id="item">
    <option *ngFor="let itm of items" [ngValue]="itm">
        {{itm.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

In Component:

```js
compareFn(item1, item2): boolean {
    return item1 && item2 ? item1.Id === item2.Id : item1 === item2;
}
```

<kbd>[SAMPLE WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hf3g6f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)</kbd>

Find more details [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor)

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is compareWith an angular material directive? What are item1 and item2?. Your demo works fine but I am unable to even get my component to accept the compareFn as written.

Comment: no it is built in function with angular and `compareWith` support `<select>` tag. it is not related to angular material. `compareWith` takes a function which has two arguments that why there are `item1` and `item2`.  If `compareWith` is given, Angular selects option by the return value of the function.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue for now by creating a separate component but will try the compareWith the first chance I get. Thanks coder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose the variables in " " to get their value.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="item" name='item' id="item">
      <option *ngFor="let itm of items" [value]="itm.Id">{{itm.name}}</option>
 </select>
```